# Use jQuery to convert table to div's and append th in front of each td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to convert all tables to divs and add the th html or contents of the th in from of each td that is converted to a div.

So my table would look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 4</th>
      <th>Title 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>               
</table>
```

And I want to convert it so it is like this:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="row-fname"><span class="fname-label">TH Data</span> : <span class="fname-data">Data 1</span></div>
<div class="row-lname"><span class="lname-label">TH Data</span> : <span class="lname-data">Data 2</span></div>
<div class="row-address"><span class="address-label">TH Data</span> : <span class="address-data">Data 3</span></div>
<div class="row-city"><span class="city-label">TH Data</span> : <span class="city-data">Data 4</span></div>
<div class="row-state"><span class="state-label">TH Data</span> : <span class="state-data">Data 5</span></div>
```

I found this code that almost works but can figure out how to make it get the th if there are any th's and add them before each td's data span.

```
$('.content table').replaceWith(function() {
    var html = '';

    $('tr', this).each(function() {         
        html += '<div class="box grey-bg">';
        $('th, td', this).each(function() {
            html += '<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
        });
        html += '</div>';
    });

    return '<div class="">' + html + '</div>';
});
```

Any help would be soooo greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why don't you just use divs to begin with?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with <table> when used for *tabular* data. Otherwise, reference **nmford**'s comment.

Comment: I have a need to convert a table that i can not adjust (dynamic cms driven) on screens that are smaller than 320 pixels and all of the responsive table solutions are not an option. I know i know very odd request but i really appreciate anyone who can help me :)

Comment: just fyi i am using this code with this...var width = parseInt($(window).width());
if (width<=320){

Comment: Also any speed improvements to the jQuery code i have is welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
$('.content table').replaceWith(function() {

    var $th = $(this).find('th'); // get headers
    var th = $th.map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get(); // and their values

    $th.closest('tr').remove(); // then remove them

    var $d = $('<div>', { 'class': 'box' });

    $('tr', this).each(function(i, el) {
        var $div = $('<div>', {'class': 'inner'}).appendTo($d);
        $('td', this).each(function(j, el) {
            var n = j + 1;
            var $row = $('<div>', {
                'class': 'row-' + n
            });
            $row.append(
            $('<span>', {
                'class': 'label-' + n,
                text: th[j]
            }), ' : ', $('<span>', {
                'class': 'data-' + n,
                text: $(this).text()
            })).appendTo($div);
        });
    });

    return $d;
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/UK395/

Comment: Very nice! what about if i dont know how many columns or names there are going to be? maybe make it increment numerically?

Comment: @Aaron yeah, that could work - the value `i` in the `.each` callback is the current column number so you could use that instead of `titles[i]`.

Comment: if you add more tr with td's it does not add the title in front of those. Only adds it to the first ones. Any ideas and this is an awesome solution too!!!

Comment: @Aaron see updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/UK395/, but you need to clarify whether there should be an extra "box" for each row, or just one for the whole table.

Comment: Wow! very cool! well it would have a div around the each row and one around the whole table. Also any way to remove the array part completely? This is awesome work! :)

Comment: WOW! this is awesome! you are a genius!! any way to add a : between the label and data?

Comment: @Aaron sure, see newest rev (13)

Comment: OMG! you even added css to show the styles and boxes!!! Amazing work!!! One last question. What if i have multiple tables on the page? Will it do this for all tables? I did a quick test and seems like it only does the first one.

Comment: @Aaron it works for me with multiple tables - just make sure you use the right selector in the very first line.

Comment: You are right! i am ding dong and forgot to put the class. You are amazing and i can not begin to tell you how much i appreciate the help with this!!! Thank you THANK YOU!!! :)

Comment: @Aaron up votes and accepting answers are the usual token of appreciation around here ;-)

Comment: You got it!!! i tried to up vote but since i just joined i need a rep of 15. Thanks again for all the help and super awesome solution!!!! :D

Answer (score 4):

Here is my improvisation :)

Add `data-name` tags to each `<th>` in order to distinguish the names of the fields:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th data-name="fname">Title 1</th>
        <th data-name="lname">Title 2</th>
        <th data-name="address">Title 3</th>
        <th data-name="city">Title 4</th>
        <th data-name="state">Title 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>               
</table>​
```

And try the code below. At least you will get exactly the structure you need.

```
$("table").replaceWith(function() {
    var block = $("<div />").addClass("box");
    $("tr:first th", this).each(function() {
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var spanLabel = $("<span />").addClass(name + "-label").html(this.innerHTML);
        var spanData = $("<span />").addClass(name + "-data");
        $("<div />").addClass("row-" + name).append(spanLabel, " : ", spanData).appendTo(block);
    });
    $("tr:last td", this).each(function(index) {
        block.children("div:eq(" + index + ")").children(":last").html(this.innerHTML);
    });
    return block;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BsUVA/

---

**UPDATE.** If you unable to add extra `data` attributes to `<th>` tags, there is not a big problem. For not hardcoding, we can move the names to array (as follows) and use it instead.

```
var names = [
    "fname",
    "lname",
    "address",
    "city",
    "state"
];
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BsUVA/1/

Comment: This is so incredibly awesome but sadly i am unable to add the data-name= to the th. The table is generated dynamically by the cms and is a standard plain jane generic table. :(

Comment: oh but thank you soooo much for the quick response and help!!! you ROCK VisioN!!!

Comment: @Aaron There is no problem, you can use array of names then. Check the update!

Comment: Wow! you are freaking awesome! The one issue i dont always know what or how many th's there will be. I am amazed at how fast you came up with this solution!!!

Comment: @Aaron I'm sure you will find a way with this starting point. You are welcome :)

Comment: how about making it use numbers so it would be "row-1", "label-1", data-1 and increase?

Comment: You have given me an awesome starting point and your code is almost perfect! thank you so much for the fast help!

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!! haha! this is awesome!!! One last question...What if i have multiple tables on the page?

Comment: @Aaron LOL You can try. It will work fine. However class names will be the same throughout each table. If you need to add individual classes (e.g. "row-1-1"), you can use indexes of *each* table and add them to class name, like we did (i.e. "row-1", "label-1", etc). That's exactly a job for you ;)

Comment: just noticed if you have several rows of data it only creates the first row with the th and td divs.

I modified your table with more rows od data but still only shows one row for out put. Add in more than one tr with td's.

Comment: i am ok with having the same class for each set of rows and divs. This is almost perfect my friend! Still amazed at how fast you developed this solution! Do you dream in code!?!? haha!

Comment: @Aaron Well, this is the last solution before I go to sleep: http://jsfiddle.net/BsUVA/5/. It handles multiple tables and multiple rows of data. The class names go as follows: `row-<tableIndex>-<thIndex>`, `data-<tableIndex>-<thIndex>-<tdIndex>`. Hopefully, this is the solution you've been expected. LOL

Comment: almost!! it is supposed to have the label and data in thier own box. So you would have the title and data 1-5 in a box for a row and then the title and the data 6-10 for in a row.

Comment: i cant tell you how much i appreciate the help!!! yThank you thank you thank you!!! :)