# How can I convert my tables to divs

Tags: html, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

Well, I hope that it is possible to convert the  and related tags to `<div>`. I am using SimpleHTMLDomParser and it is not possible to go for another parser in this stage. Here's what I have tried:

```
    $html=preg_replace('/<table[^>]*>/ism', '',$html);
    $html=preg_replace('/<\/table>/ism', '<br/>',$html);
    $html=preg_replace('/<(tr|td|th)[^>]*>/ism', '',$html);
    $html=preg_replace('/<\/(tr|td|th)[^>]*>/ism', '<br/>',$html);
```

To strip out the tables, but now I need to convert all the "`<table>`","`<tr>`","`<td>`","`<th>`" to (nested) "`<div>`" tags (the table changes to a div, its internal tags to nested divs).

How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728445/use-jquery-to-convert-table-to-divs-and-append-th-in-front-of-each-td

Comment: **Thanks for quick reply**, but isn't it possible to use `preg_replace` for the purpose? Please view my code again.